# SQL Insert Into a newly created column ,data placed after the last row of the previous column

Tags: java, sql, database, sqlite

I  have a problem with a SQL statement. I have a java app with a button to add a column into a database. For every new date, I have a new column created, which is done using  the following query

```
final String queryCreate = "alter table Currency add  '"+  newColumn + "'  decimal ";
```

When I try to populate the column with data using the following query:

```
final String queryAdd = "insert into Currency( '" + newColumn + "' ) values(1.95583)";
```

The data is added below the last row of the previous column.
like this:
https://postimg.org/image/579gjmyzj/

My question is why the insert statement does what it does in my situation, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish exactly with your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`INSERT` creates new records, if you want to modify existing records you need to use `UPDATE`.

For example, to modify the first record:

```
"UPDATE Currency SET " + newColumn + " = 1.95583 WHERE Currency_ID = 1"
```

Comment: The SQL query should look like this :  final String queryAdd = "UPDATE Currency SET " + " '"+ newColumn + "' "+ " = 1.95583 WHERE Currency_ID = 1"; .

Answer (score 0):

use update query
assuming strCurrencyID="1";
strCurrencyName="EUR";

final String queryAddUpdate =

if exists(Select Top 1 1 from Currency  where Currency_ID=" + strCurrencyID   +") 
Begin update Currency set " + newColumn + "=1.95583 where Currency_ID=" +strCurrencyID + " 
End 
Else 
Begin
      insert into Currency(Currency_id, Currency_name, '" + newColumn + "' ) values("+ strCurrencyID +",'" + strCurrencyName + ", 1.95583)
End"

This will update the value in in column if currency id exists if not this will insert new row.

But I think database design should be change can you explain your business requirement.